# Display array in html under eachother

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to display an array into html under eachother.

Example:

```
let cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars;
```

What I get is: Saab,Volvo,BMW

What I want is:

Saab

Volvo

BMW

Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: Please provide your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array with a `br` element. Here I've used [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)...

```js
let cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cars.join('<br/>'));
```

...but `innerHTML` would work too.

```js
let cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
document.body.innerHTML = cars.join('<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick hacky solution :)

```js
let cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
for(var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)
{
document.body.innerHTML += '<div >' + cars[i] + '</div>';
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
const list = document.getElementById("demo");

cars.forEach(car => {
  let item = document.createElement("li");
  item.innerText = car;
  list.appendChild(item);
})
```

```html
<ul id="demo"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use forEach to loop through cars array and using br tag on every append to existing content of demo element

```
let cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];


cars.forEach(v => {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += v + '<br />';
})
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MZabXm

```js
let cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];


cars.forEach(v => {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += v + '<br />';
})
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var content = '';
for(var i=0; i<cars.length; i++){
    content+= "<div>"+cars[i]+"</div>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = content;
```